# wp_enqueue_script function not loading the js

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I wrote a function to load script and stylesheet for a Wordpress theme but i guess is not working properly. The stylesheets are being loaded but i can't get the js to be loaded. Any clue of what I've missed here?

```
function kakadu_setup(){
   
    wp_enqueue_style('style', get_stylesheet_uri(), NULL, microtime(), 'all');
    wp_enqueue_style('google-fonts', '//fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Source+Sans+Pro:ital,wght@0,400;0,600;0,700;0,900;1,400;1,600;1,700;1,900&display=swap');
    wp_enqueue_style('andmars', get_theme_file_uri( '/css/andmars.css' ), NULL, microtime(), 'all');
    wp_enqueue_style('custom', get_theme_file_uri( '/css/custom.css' ), NULL, microtime(), 'all');
    wp_enqueue_script('scripts', get_theme_file_uri( '/js/scripts.js' ), NULL, microtime(), true);
  
    
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'kakadu_setup');
```

Any help would be great!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The 3rd parameter of **wp_enqueue_script()** would be an array() of dependency, not the NULL value.

Try this:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'scripts', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/scripts.js', array(), microtime(), true );
```

Comment: Thanks man. I've tried but no lucky. I'm intrigued with this.

Comment: Have you tried replacing `microtime()` with `false`?

Comment: Didn't work. The curious thing is that when i use <script> tag in footer my custom js works fine. So I think that is not a js problem. But not getting to wp_enqueue_script to work.

Answer (score 0):

As Aman Mehra suggested, I would not fill in NULL. Also, the name "scripts" and the microtime() function doesn't look right.

If you read the [WordPress developers handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/), you can see the args:
wp_enqueue_script( $handle, $src, $deps, $ver, $in_footer );

So maybe try:
wp_enqueue_script('kakadu-scripts', get_theme_file_uri( '/js/scripts.js' ), '','', true);

If that still doesn't work, the issue is somewhere else and you'll have to give more information.

Answer (score 0):

```
function kakadu_setup() {
wp_enqueue_style( 'google-fonts', '//fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Source+Sans+Pro:ital,wght@0,400;0,600;0,700;0,900;1,400;1,600;1,700;1,900&display=swap' );
wp_enqueue_style( 'andmars', get_theme_file_uri( '/css/andmars.css' ), null, "1.0" );
wp_enqueue_style( 'custom', get_theme_file_uri( '/css/custom.css' ), null, "1.0" );
wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_stylesheet_uri(), null, time() );

wp_enqueue_script( 'scripts', get_theme_file_uri( '/js/scripts.js' ), array( 'jquery' ), null, true );
```

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'kakadu_setup' );

Comment: Add these code in your theme & try again.